# ERROR occur while installing opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

An error occurred while building with CMake.
Command:
cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
Source directory:
C:\Users\POOJAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irhvtcq9\opencv-python
Working directory:
C:\Users\POOJAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irhvtcq9\opencv-python_skbuild\win-amd64-3.7\cmake-build
Please see CMake's output for more information.

---

Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Running setup.py clean for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: Try installing it via conda on a virtual environment

Comment: you got a solution for this?